# How to transform a contiguously allocated matrix into a row allocated one?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

For various reasons I have to pass a matrix as a buffer to a function but after that I would like to transform that matrix which is allocated as one contiguous block of memory into one that makes individual allocations for each row.
Here is the function that I'm using at the moment.

```
T** makeRowAllocations(T** matrix, unsigned height, unsigned width) {
    T** a = new T*[height];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        a[i] = new T[width];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    delete[] matrix[0];
    delete[] matrix;
    return a;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more memory-efficient way to do things (without keeping what are essentially 2 matrices at the same time in memory). Is there a way to gradually deallocate memory from the first matrix?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No there's no way to "gradually deallocate memory" if it was allocated as a single piece.

Comment: Agree with @ProXicT, what is the *real* problem you're trying to solve? If you need one type of matrix (a jagged one) then why create the contiguously allocated matrix to begin with? And if you want a jagged matrix, why not use a vector of vectors?

Comment: I need it as a contiguos block in the begining in order to extract data from a file. I have very large matrices and keeping them as contiguous blocks of memory is not feasible. It's very likely that i wouldn't have such huge blocks of memory on the heap all the time to store them.

Comment: the bigger the matrix the more you gain by keeping it in contiguous memory, so I dont really buy your argument. Did you really encounter out-of-memory?

Comment: Still it occupies more memory to keep arrays of arrays rather than contiguous blocks.

Comment: No I didn't encounter allocation problems yet. I was just assuming that it could be a problem.

Comment: thats not a very useful assumption. A much better one is to assume everything will be fine and use a `std::vector` or better an `std::array`. Dont do premature optimizations

Comment: @VMircan May I ask whether there is a dimension  (height or width) that is constexpr (clamped down at compile time) or even better both?

Comment: @sandthorn Yes there are fixed dimensions.